# How to run multiple calculations using `oninput` (HTML5)?

Tags: forms, html, textbox

I need a way of running a few calculations based on the contents of a single text box. I'm currently using a form, with the text box what accepts numeric values. I then use the `oninput` to calculate the other values eg.

```
<form oninput="x.value=7+y.value">
```

However I need a way of running multiple calculations using `oninput`. Is this possible? If so how? If not, what are my other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue. You can do something like so:

```
<form oninput="x.value=7+y.value;z.value=y.value+300">
```

Comment: I can't yet - as soon as it allows me to I will though. Thanks.